# Solve for a vector given one component and direction expressed as a unit vector

Tags: math, vectormath

Say that I have the y-component of a 3D vector and I have a unit vector expressing the direction of the final desired vector. How would I go about solving for the X and Z components? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple ratio, where `u*` are unit vector components

```
 dx = ux * dy / uy
 dz = uz * dy / uy
```

(because unit vector components are defined as `ux = dx / Len` with common `Len`, and `dy/uy` is really vector length)